# Making a pure RESTful data-service service in Python (no web pages - just calls & responses)

Tags: python, rest

I would like to build a pure data services applications in Python.

It will sit on a server, manipulate data, and then will serve the results of various analysis when called via RESTful API.

There will be no webpages - just RESTful calls to the app, server side processing, and a return.

I am thinking of using flask for this - is this a suitable choice or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure Flask is a great web framework you can use to create web api. You can start following this post for example: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

For my part, I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) and [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Django can do a lot more than just serving as a restful backend for sure, but using Tastypie with it provided me the best framework to create my restful api. Plus Tastypie is really well developed, great community, and you'll always find someone to answer your questions on stackoverflow if you got a problem. It's documentation is also really nice with a lot of examples.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to use Bottle to build a clean, RESTful API in front of an existing service.  I've used it several times (Bottle + Apache + mod_wsgi) with great success.

Flask is probably another good choice.  Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYjPIMe0BhA) and (its corresponding [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/r1chardj0n3s/web-microframework-battle)) that compares several web microframeworks.  It's a couple of years old, but still might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With Django I used Tasty Pie but I later switched to Rest Framework:

http://django-rest-framework.org/

Rest framework is really good if you are comfortable in writing django apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try Django-Tastypie framework http://tastypieapi.org/
or [Sandman](http://www.sandman.io) (on GitHub [here](http://www.github.com/jeffknupp/sandman))

Answer (score 1):

If you're using flask, you should check out the flask_restful library:

- http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/